# Poner color a un cuadro dentro de una celda

Tags: html, css, angular, scss, frontend

Estoy intentando poner el diseño del componente de `dx-color-box` en una celda:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando la librería `devexpress` eh intentado de esta manera considerando que el color es un dato guardado en la base de datos

```
  <dxi-column  dataField="colour" [minWidth]="10" dataType="string" caption="Color">
    <div class="card-colour"></div>                                                
 </dxi-column>
```

```css
.card-color {
  height: 35px;
  width: 35px;
    color:#337ab7 !important;
}
```

pero no me resulta solo me sale así
[image: aquí muestra el listado]

Comment: A simple vista parece que tienes incoherencia en el nombre de clase. En un sitio pones `<div class="card-colour"></div>` y en el css pones `.card-colors {`. Me huele a error tipográfico.

Comment: ya lo corregí pero no hay resultados

Comment: Si en tu navegador haces clic con el botón derecho del ratón sobre el texto que quieres cambiar el color y seleccionas "Inspeccionar" en el menu contextual que aparece, se te abrirá el inspector de objetos y podras ver el codigo fuente de ese texto y como está representado. Tambien puedes inspeccionar sus css, etc... quizás alli encuentres lo que le está ocurriendo o puedas copiar ese trozo de HTML puro y pegarlo en la pregunta para ver si podemos ayudarte. (entiendo que eso que haces genera HTML, que no lo se realmente, pero esta en tus etiquetas de la pregunta)

Answer (score 0):

Fijate que tu div tiene como clase: card-colour
`<div class="card-colour"></div>`
y cuando se le aplican los estilos en el archivo css se llama a la clase
`card-color{..]`